# Django: combine values of two models fields into one new model field (3 different models)

Tags: django

I have three different models.

```
class A(models.Model):
    request_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True , editable=False)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)

class B(models.Model):
        request = models.ForeignKey(to=Request, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True, to_field='request_id')
        state = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)

class C(models.Model):
        request = models.ForeignKey(to=Request, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True, to_field='request_id')
        db_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)

        @property
        def db_name(self):
            return f"{A.department}_{B.state}"
```

I would like to auto populate the db_name column as follow "DEPARTMENT_STATE". I thought that db_name would do this, but for some reason it isn't working at all, and I don't get why?

There is relation on ID between model A -> B, A -> C (but for some reason the values are NULL in the table of model B and C).

Does someone know how I can auto populate db_name which requires not manual/user input?

Comment: Please, post your whole models or at least their relations fields to each other so we can help you

Comment: db_name property is in C model?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I aligned the indent.

Comment: The source code still does not make any sense due to your "obfuscation". Please just post your actual models.py file, so we can actually help you.

Answer (score 0):

```py
class A(models.Model):
    request_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True , editable=False)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)

class B(models.Model):
        request = models.ForeignKey(to=Request, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True, to_field='request_id')
        state = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)

class C(models.Model):
        request = models.ForeignKey(to=Request, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True, to_field='request_id')
        db_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)

        @property
        def db_name(self):
            request_state = B.objects.filter(request=self.request).first().state
            return f"{self.request.department}_{request_state}"
```

I think you'd have to query for C to be aware of the relationship between A and B.

[Backward relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)